# Entity Framework Core & Oracle: ignoring nullability of navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, odp.net

I'm using Entity Framework Core to access an Oracle database and am getting an InvalidCastException saying "Column contains NULL data" on a field that's marked as nullable. It's a navigation property on a one-to-many relationship that can be null (not all parent records have children) but instead of working how the docs say, it's throwing errors when trying to convert this null to an int.

The entities:

```
[Table("BASES")]
public class Base
{
    public int BaseId {get; set;}
    public int? BaseEntityId {get; set;}    
    public virtual List<AddressLink>? AddressLinks { get; set; } = [];
    // Other properties omitted
}


[Table("ADDR_LINK")]
public class AddressLink
{
    [Key]
    [Column("LINK_ID")]
    public int LinkId { get; set; }
    [Column("ENTITY_ID")]
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public Base Base { get; set; }
    // Other properties omitted
}

// And in the context:
modelBuilder.Entity<Base>()
    .HasMany(b => b.AddressLinks)
    .WithOne(l => l.Base)
    .HasForeignKey(l => l.EntityId)
    .HasPrincipalKey(b => b.BaseEntityId);
```

When selecting a base with no BaseEntityId, all the documentation implies that that base should simply not have a collection of AddressLinks, but instead it's throwing an exception that the "Column contains NULL data".

Edited to add: In a perfect world I'd redo the database structure to point at the Base's primary key but sadly this is the back-end of a piece of commercial software that we license, so I'm not able to make any changes to the database layout.

Comment: I don't think your mapping is correct. The FK on AddressLink MUST point at a non-nullable principal key, usually the primary key on the Base table. (Which EF would use by default if you remove the `HasPrincipalId`)

Comment: Yeah, sadly the database layout is beyond my control so the fields join where they join. I'll edit the question to include that. Any thoughts on a way around? The only way I can think of is putting [NotMapped] on the Base's AddressLinks property and manually adding them in with a separate query as required.

Comment: Then it may not work. Is by chance the AddressLink referenced by multiple other tables in the DB? Or does it actually have a FK defined back to this Base table? If it doesn't have an actual FK back to Base then you likely won't be able to set up the relationship like this. Querying the data for something like `select count(1) from AddressLinks al left join bases b on al.entityId = b.baseentityid where b.baseid is null` If that returns > 0 then the referential integrity of the data won't satisfy a relationship like you want.